# How I can get the value of a property of principal as object and not as a string?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

**How I can get the value of a property of principal as object and not as a string?**

I have my custom User Object that extends UserDetails.

**Example:**

This will print as a string the property allTask

```
<sec:authentication property="principal.user.allTask"/>
```

I want take value  property of principal as object for save on request using the tag

```
<c:set var="task" value="${principal.user.allTask}"/>
```

I want not push a bean principal on request from Controller.!

Answer (score 0):

i do not really understand your question but,i have a post on my blog regarding this:

http://giannisapi.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/spring-3-spring-security-implementing-custom-userdetails-with-hibernate/
 also string is an object as well so by getting string you are getting an object.
i hope it will help you. read it and let me know if you need more help

Comment: I know that a string in java is also an object. I want to retrieve the object, do not want your representation as a string.

Comment: the post above a gave you it gives you what you want. but you must follow it closely as even the database structure should be followed. i do not see why your "${principal.user.allTask}". are you sure you do put your object in a map in order to be available on the jsp page?